# Root UIWindow to external screen/display over Wifi

Tags: ios, wifi, external, uiwindow

I already know (and test) how to display an UIWindow on to an external screen when my device (iPhone/iPad) is connected to the screen using the VGA connector.

But I want to do it without any wire. So I want to know if there is a solution to do it over Wifi. There is some application which can root video to other devices. iOS 4.3 will be able to display video from iPhone/iPad to an Apple TV for exemple ... but me I want to display the content of an UIWindow, not a simple video file.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 Good question: Have never seen or heard of anything being able to do this..good luck

Comment: thanks ... but when I think about it seems really hard to do if it is not "planned" in the device itself. so I think my question has no answer :(